# Exit Google Script if cell already populated with data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, eventtrigger

I have a script that is doing simple automation. I need to check to see if data already exists and if so, simply exit the entire function, rather than continue setting values. How do I do that with this script? Thanks!

```
function onEdit() {
  var sheetName = "SUPPORT INFO";
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (s.getName() !== sheetName) return;
  var r = s.getActiveCell();
  if( r.getColumn() != 2 ) { //checks the column
    var row = r.getRow();
    var date = new Date();
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B' + row.toString()).setValue(date);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A' + row.toString()).setValue("Closed");
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('O' + row.toString()).setValue("TECH1");
  };
};
```

Comment: "Your" script already does this kind of guard, when it checks the name of whatever sheet is open when the script gets to that line of code. Simply adapt your script to also check the given value of the cell that needs to be checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Determine what the logic of the program flow should be.  If you need the code to only work with one column, then you can exclude every thing else.

Exclude all other columns:

```
var theActiveRange = sheet.getActiveCell();

columnNumberToUse = X;

if ( theActiveRange.getColumn() !== columnNumberToUse) {return;}//quit if this column 
//is any column other than X

if (!theActiveRange.getValue()) {return;}
```

So, using this code, if you assign the variable `columnNumberToUse` a value of 2, then when the column number **is** 2 the code will continue to run.  So, if the code gets past the lines:

```
columnNumberToUse = 2;

if ( theActiveRange.getColumn() !== columnNumberToUse) {return;}//quit if this column 
//number is not equal to the columnNumberToUse

//If the code gets to here - then you know the active range is column 2
```

You need to understand the "not" operator, which is an exclamation point.

```
var is_it_true = 1 !== 5;
```

The number 1 is not equal to 5, so the above line of code will have a value of true for the variable `is_it_true`

The example code is testing for whether the column number is not equal to 2.

Comment: Will this check column 2's cell in the active row?

Comment: Nooo... why the use of `getActive____` instead of using the event object in an event-triggered function?

Comment: @tehhowch I've experienced event objects failing.  That's why I avoid using them whenever possible.  It's certainly a good question to ask.  You could post a question about whether to use the event object or getActive_XYZ().

Comment: Thank you. I sincerely appreciate the positive and very helpful response.